# two identical pattern rules what would happen?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following situation: In one makefile I have two identical pattern rules.

```
%.hex: %.ihex
    cp $< $@
```

few lines further

```
%.hex: %.ihex
    cp $< $@
```

What is actually happening, when the second pattern rule is encountered?

Answer (score 1):

GNU make accepts this as a redefinition of the pattern rule without warnings, and executes the second definition.  The first is ignored.